# Example of non-cocompact lattice in a specific topological group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

An exercise in Dave Witte Morris' *Introduction to Arithmetic Groups* asks the reader to suppose the following.

- $\Gamma$ is a non-cocompact lattice in a topological group $H$
- $H$ has a compact, open subgroup $K$

The exercise asks the reader to show that $\Gamma$ has a non-trivial element of finite order. While the exercise itself is easy, I'm having difficulty coming with an example of such a group $H$, and a lattice $\Gamma$.

Since $K$ has to be an *open* compact subgroup, that means the identity component of $H$ must be compact, and therefore $H$ is the semidirect product of a compact connected group $H^{\circ}$, and a discrete group $D = H/H^{\circ}$. Given such a group $H^{\circ} \ltimes D$, one now needs to find a non-cocompact lattice $\Gamma$, and
this is where I'm stuck. I can't think of any examples of such lattices. If anyone has any examples, I'd be interested in knowing what they are. Thanks.

Comment: See examples in https://www.amazon.com/Tree-Lattices-Progress-Mathematics-Hyman/dp/1461274133

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example is $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{F}[t])$ in $\mathbf{SL}_2\big(\mathbf{F}(\!(t^{-1})\!)\big)$ for $n\ge 2$ and $\mathbf{F}$ a finite field.

Another family of examples (in which the ambient group is solvable, not finitely generated), is due to [Bader, Caprace, Gelander and Mozes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06220); here the group $G$ is defined from a sequence of finite fields $F_{(n)}$, and defined as $G=\bigoplus_nF_{(n)}\rtimes \prod_nF_{(n)}^*$. The lattice is abelian. See details therein.

All these groups are indeed far from torsion-free: in the latter case these lattices are infinite locally finite groups. In the first arithmetic case, the lattice contains unipotent subgroups, which are infinite $p$-elementary abelian groups ($p$ being the characteristic of the field).